# Loop through random numbers in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply 'For loop' in excel VBA and I have to go to cell numbers 2, 8, 15, 21, 28, 35, 49, 56, 63, 70, 76; as there is no fixed pattern/sequence,I am not able to use Step command, how should I go about it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use an array and loop through it.

```
dim vars as variant, v as long
vars = array(2, 8, 15, 21, 28, 35, 49, 56, 63, 70, 76)
for v = lbound(vars) to ubound(vars)
    'do something with cells(vars(v), <some column>) or cells(<some row>, vars(v))
next v
```